# SyntaxError when calling an async static function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm playing a bit with async/await of Node 8.3.0 and I have some issue with static function.

*MyClass.js*

```
class MyClass {
  static async getSmthg() {
    return true;
  }
}
module.exports = MyClass
```

*index.js*

```
try {
  const result = await MyClass.getSmthg();
} catch(e) {}
```

With this code I've got an `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` on `MyClass`.
Why is that? Can't use a static function with `await` or have I made a mistake?

Thank you

Comment: You did import MyClass?

Comment: You could only use `await` inside `async` function. Do you wrap the code from `index.js` with a function?

Comment: Forgot to wrap it into an `async` function. Thank you all

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The await operator can only be used inside a async function if your node or browser don't support top level await and it doesn't run as a module.

You would have to do this instead

```
(async () => {
  try {
    const result = await MyClass.getSmthg();
  } catch(e) {}
})()
```

the alternative can be to set `"type": "module"` in package.json

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use await in the main script... Try this

```
async function test(){
    try {
      const result = await MyClass.getSmthg();
      return result;
    } catch(e) {}
}
test().then(function(res){console.log(res)})
```

`await` can only be used in an `async` function, and `async` function will return a `promise` if not called with `await`.

Comment: erm, correction: you can use await in the "main" script... But it can only be used inside an async function.

Comment: Yes, maybe my wording wasn't that good... By main script I wanted to mean the code executed directly in the global scope... AKA not in a function.

Comment: @Salketer feel free to edit your answer so that it is correct.